# Produce an infinite list of identical elements in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In Haskell programming language, how can we produce an infinite list of identical elements.What is the code in Haskell in which user inputs some number and infinite list of that number generated. I had practiced but it was not successful. My logic is below:
Code:

```
repeat :: a -> [a]
repeat x = xs where 
          xs=x*xs
```

Comment: The [`repeat`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=repeat&scope=set%3Astackage) function already exists.

Comment: Lists are constructed with `:`, not `*`.

Comment: This is basically correct, except that '*' isn't right operator.

Comment: @hnefatl btw OP's implementation (if they had used the right operator) is more efficient than yours -- it will create a small referential cycle rather than producing a whole bunch of cons cells.  You can see this by checking memory usage of `let xs = repeat 1 in (xs!!(10^6)) + (xs!!(10^6))`.

Comment: @hnefatl: by using a variable, you basically produce a linked list with a loop. As a result, you can fold sometimes iterate over the list in constant memory.

Comment: @luqui (and @WillemVanOnsem) Huh, that's cool - thanks for telling me!

Comment: @amina one of the really nice things about haskell is that you can go straight to the source to find the definitions of functions like these: eg https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#repeat

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are quite close, but the strange thing here is that you write `x*xs`, `(*)` is an operator that is usually used to *multiply* numbers, it is a function that is a method of the `Num` typeclass.

In case you construct a list, you use the *list data constructors*. The two data constructors are `[] :: [a]` (the empty list), and `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`. Here it makes sense to use the `(:)` operator: we prepend `xs` with `x`, so we can write:

```
repeat :: a -> [a]
repeat x = xs
    where xs = x : xs
```

Here we thus construct for a given `x` parameter, a linked list that looks like:

```
+-------+
|  (:)  |<-.
+---+---+  |
| o | o |  |
+-|-+-|-+  |
  v   `----'
  x
```

So a "cons" element where the tail refers to itself. As a result if you perform *some* list processing, it is possible that the memory usage remains constant (without garbage collection) and Haskell thus keeps looping in the *same* cons object.

Comment: Alternatively, `repeat x = x : repeat x`.

Comment: @AJFarmar: this will result in linear memory usage in case you iterate over the list. As they say "*if you name it, Haskell remembers it*". If you use `x : repeat x`, then you will lazily keep calling the tail. With your given repeat function, you will eventually run out of memory if you call `let l = repeat 14 in l!!100000000000 + l!!100000000000`